# Can anyone provide me answer/guide on how to design a turing machine for this case?

Tags: turing-machines

I tried, but I could not design a turing machine for the following problem:

Turing machine that takes as input a tape containing a series of n 1s,
where n >= 0, terminated by an = sign. The Turing machine head is initially positioned on
the leftmost 1. The end state should be a tape containing the input, followed by the reverse of the sequence of 0s and 1s that represents n in binary.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take would be to effectively reduce this to a machine that adds one to a binary number that is written left to right rather than right to left.  Once you figure out that logic you'd just need to mark the end of the input and write a zero after that.  Then for each 1 in the input, mark it and add one to the  binary number found after the input.